# Angular Material: Prevent layout resizing when select box value is chosen

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Using Angular Material: this is how the select box behaves after selecting input
[image]
After choice element gets attribiute `text-size-adjust: 100%` what causing width change.

You can check this with codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNOdKP?editors=1000

How to prevent this behaviour to maintain fixed width?

Dirty fix is too add bunch of `&nbsp;` in `<div><div/>` just under `</md-select>` code (see last example in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNOdKP?editors=1000))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less dirty solution might be setting 
`ng-class="{'md-select-fixed-width': true}"`, when `md-select-fixed-width: 140px;`
so i.e. select will look like:

```
 <md-select name="startYear4" 
               ng-model="ctrl.year4" 
               md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" 
               ng-class="{'md-select-fixed-width':true}"
               required>
      <md-option ng-repeat="year4 in [2017, 2016, 2015]" value={{year4}} ng-bind="year4">{{year4}}</md-option>
 </md-select>
```

and css:

```
.md-select-fixed-width {
   width: 140px;
}
```

See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWZYOZ?editors=1000)